# Postgresql create function error

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

What am I doing wrong in the following function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extended_sales(area_type varchar, area_code varchar, dpci varchar) RETURNS TABLE(task_id bigint, location_id int)as

$BODY$

BEGIN 
    IF area_type = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where T.task_payload->>'str_area_type_i'='3';
    ELSE IF area_type = 2 THEN
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where T.due_date < '2017-10-06';
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where task_payload->>'str_area_type_i'='1' and task_payload->>'str_area_c'='7'  and due_date < '2016-11-07';
    END IF;


END

$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

When I run the above function it gives the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 17: $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't try to compile it, but don't you need a semicolon after `END`?

Comment: do you need `return;` before end?

Comment: @Hambone: No, you don't. That's optional at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two IF statements and one END IF. Use ELSIF if you want to have a single [IF statement.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS)

```
    IF area_type = 1 THEN
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where T.task_payload->>'str_area_type_i'='3';
    ELSIF area_type = 2 THEN
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where T.due_date < '2017-10-06';
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY select T.task_id, T.location_id from store_price.task T where task_payload->>'str_area_type_i'='1' and task_payload->>'str_area_c'='7'  and due_date < '2016-11-07';
    END IF;
```